# BackgroundColorSpan not working with Html.fromhtml()

Tags: android, html

I am making a note app and I want the user to be able to highlight text. The problem is when The user sets highlighted text, then saves it to the database I have. It has to be retrieved through the code

```
Html.fromhtml()
```

In order for the Rich text to save. Even though this code above saves bold, italic, and others. It will not save highlight color. I know the html code is saving to the database but the code above cant see to know that its there. Anybody know how to save background highlight color so

```
Html.fromhtml()
```

can retrieve it

Comment: Can you show your data in database?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but neither `Html.fromHtml()` nor `Html.toHtml()` do anything with `BackgroundColorSpan`.